# Oracle performance improvement (need to reduce the time taken)

Tags: performance, oracle12c

I have a situation where I have to read the file having at least 1 million accounts and store them in a vector, and need to update the table (table_name) for all the accounts read from the file finally need to commit. Conversion of file in to vector is completed in few minutes but the later process is taking 2 to 3 hours (for updating the table). How to optimise the process? Any suggestions to reduce the time? I am working with oracle 12 c. I have searched many blogs I didn't find any proper help.

Comment: i tried to commit the transactions for every 2000 records,it has reduced 10 to 15 mins,but i think its not the proper step to improve performance

Comment: Have a look at this [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330) discussion.

Comment: How many rows are in the table being updated?